# Deriving a formula for a confidence interval

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Derive a formula for a $(1-\alpha)100\%$ C.I. for $\mu_x -\mu_y $ for data that has the following properties:

A random  sample $X_1,X_2...X_n \ are \ i.i.d ~N(\mu_x, \sigma^2 ) $

Another  random ] sample $Y_1,Y_2...Y_n \ are \ i.i.d ~N(\mu_y, 2\sigma^2 ) $

Two  random samples  are  independent and  $\sigma$  unknown

How might I approach this? I believe I need to use

$$\bar{x}-\bar{y} \pm t_{\alpha/2}(df)\sqrt{\frac{s^2_p}{n}+ \frac{s^2_p}{m}} $$

But I'm not sure how to go about finding $ s^2_p $ and $ df $

I know normally $$ s^2_p = \frac{(n-1)s^2_x+(m-1)s^2_y}{n+m-2} $$

And $ df= n + m -2 $

But that can't be the case here, I don't think. How could I approach this? I've been beating my head into the wall the whole evening over this. 
Thanks!

Comment: You used dollar signs for simple prose and  I edited with some pain.

Comment: What are you studying?

Comment: I think you should have a plus sign in the numerator of your pooled variance normally.  Consider looking at the Welch t test when variances are not assumed to be equal.